# Persistent OPcache in CLI mode

Tags: php, opcache

I have a PHP script that executes background script in CLI mode via:

`exec('php file.php > /dev/null &');`

OPcache is enabled in both modes, however I have noticed that in cli mode opcache resets on every call. Is it possible to make it persist? If not, what's the point of enabling opcache in cli mode?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `file_cache enabled, too: https://pierre-schmitz.com/using-opcache-to-speed-up-your-cli-scripts/. Also, you say both modes, but can you confirm you are editing the INI that is read by CLI, which is often different that other SAPIs

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've enabled `file_cache` and `file_cache_only` to avoid shared memory altogether and I can see the opcode files created on disk, however when I run `opcache_get_status` it shows `opcache_enabled => false`

Comment: As for the configuration, yes, I can confirm via `php -i` that they are set.